# Azure Configuration Settings (cscfg) with fallback to a Settings.Setting file

Tags: c#, .net, azure, configuration, settings

Defining a configuration setting in an Azure ServiceConfiguration (`.cscfg`) is compelling because I can then change the value within the Azure portal.

However, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548301/azure-configuration-settings-and-microsoft-windowsazure-cloudconfigurationmanage) `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSettings("Foo")` will fall back to looking for a `<appSettings>` value in the app.config.

Is it possible to have it fallback to a `Settings.setting` file instead?

I could create a method like this, **but is there a better/built-in way**?

```
public T GetSetting<T>(string name, T defaultValue = null)
{
    return
        !RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable
        //we could be in a non azure emulated environment (ie unit test)
        ? defaultValue 
        : RoleEnvironemt.GetConfigurationSettingValue(name)  
          ??
          //in case no value is specified in .cscfg or <appSettings>
          defaultValue;
}
```

And then have to call it like:

```
var settings = GetSetting("Example", Properties.Settings.Default.Example);
```

But this is a pain that I have to specify the `"Example"` string parameter

Comment: It [falls back](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager) to web.config and app.config already. Are you trying to implement ALM scheme where you do not check-in your connection strings in cscfg?

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov - Basically, I just didn't want to have 'magic' strings throughout my app to load configuration settings.  I wanted the strongly typed and compile constants goodness from a settings file.

Comment: Definitely - no magic strings- is the way to go. I made two such templates - one for [console](https://github.com/ognyandim/StrongTypedConfig) and one for [azure](https://github.com/ognyandim/AzureStrongConfig) app using [Castle Dictionary Adapter](http://kozmic.net/2013/11/21/on-strongly-typed-application-settings-with-castle-dictionaryadapter/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new overload for the method above and was able to pull out the name of the setting from an Expression:

```
var setting = __cloudSettingsProvider.GetSetting(
   () => Properties.Setting.Default.ExampleConfiguration);
```

So now, I can pass in the setting name *and* default value.  The method will check against `Azure config`, then `appSettings`, then `applicationSettings` and then finally the hard coded default in `Settings.Settings`.

Here's the code for the method (essentially):

```
public T GetSetting<T>(Expression<Func<T>> setting)
{
     var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) setting.Body;

     var settingName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settingName))
         throw new Exception(
            "Failed to get Setting Name " + 
            "(ie Property Name) from Expression");

     var settingDefaultValue = setting.Compile().Invoke();

     //Use the method posted in the answer to try and retrieve the
     //setting from Azure / appSettings first, and fallback to 
     //defaultValue if no override was found
     return GetSetting(
            settingName,
            settingDefaultValue);
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice! Just what I was looking for.