# Get ServiceBusTrigger name from App.config in Console App

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I have function that receive ServiceBusTrigger message:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("mysb")] string message)
{
    // do something with message
}
```

when I send message to "mysb" Azure Que - this function start to work.

**My question is**: Can I take the Que name from the App.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548301/azure-configuration-settings-and-microsoft-windowsazure-cloudconfigurationmanage) seems to answer your question.

You'll use this code: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSettings("QueueName")`

With this kind of code in your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="QueueName" value="mysb"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to sebbrochet's answer, you'll probably have to implement a custom INameResolver to get the value from the app.config file as this GitHub issue suggests.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/581
Just use %paramname% in the ServiceBus param when you want your custom resolver to kick in.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just an implementation of @Baywet's answer which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30515085/4567504) by @dprothero.

In your `Program.cs` file's `Main` Method, while registering `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration` provide an implementation of `INameResolver` to NameResolver property like

```
static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration
    {
        NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver()
    };

    //other configurations
}
```

and the `QueueNameResolver` class is like

```
public class QueueNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name].ToString();
    }
}
```

Now add a key in `<appSettings>` section of `App.config` file like

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="QueueName" value="myqueue" />
</appSettings>
```

and use it like

```
 public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("%QueueName%")] BrokeredMessage receivedMessage)
```